Is there a reason why I can't use find to scan modified files for viruses and malware?
I need to scan Linux systems for viruses/malware, on the entire file system. There are few options to consider.

One is normally what users do: Use antivirus to scan system once a day.
The second option is to find files modified in last one day and give that list to antivirus program.

I tested following bash command find on directory with 5 million empty files, and it's extremely efficient.
date;find /test/ -type f -ctime -1 1>./find_ctime.out 2>./find.errors;date
It takes only about 5 seconds.
I am using -ctime option just to overcome some program changing modification time using utility such as touch.
Most admins when they talk about a system scan, they talk about having antivirus do the complete scan.
Is there a reason why find should not be used to get a list of files modified and scan them?
EDIT: I have posted following question which may have an answer to why no antivirus seems to use "find" based incremental approach: Is there a way to use linux "find" and filter if specific process was the only one accessed it?

Why are you assuming that only new files can be altered? Your approach will exclude any files that were created long ago but which the malware has changed.

Is there some reason you couldn’t just use on-access scanning instead? That will usually get you better response times to actual threats and should do a much better job of avoiding needing a resource-heavy job to run daily.

Please do not multi-post. For the record, another copy is on Super User.

You might be able to write something with inotify-tools for logging the FS changes in the bg and then you run the AV on the modified directories. But that's just an idea, as it will be real hard to implement something like this correctly

It's probably not the worst idea as long as you also do full system scans regularly in addition to your incremental scans, however there are some downsides:
Not all exploits require file modifications
Some exploits could lay dormant in old files that simply weren't caught by old antivirus signatures.  So when new signatures are released, it's possible they find threats in old files.
File modification times are weird
There are all sorts of oddities and inconsistencies with file modification and change times in Linux.

Not all file systems support ctime and mtime and the ones that do don't always use it.
You can arbitrarily change ctime as well as mtime to whatever you want them to be
If you write directly to the disk with something like dd you can bypass mtime or ctimes
If a file is memory mapped, it can be modified without updating the mtime/ctime on disk
Files on network attached storage are just a wild west free for all
It's possible to manipulate modified times on files with hard links
You can modify the system time when modifying a file and then change it back to manipulate the file modify time

So with all that in mind if an attacker knows your antivirus scanning policy is based on modify/change time they could very easily bypass that with any one of the above methods and probably dozes of other ones.

"You can arbitrarily change ctime" citation needed. It's remotely possible you know a way to do this but the standard call for changing atime and mtime won't change ctime and the usage document says you can't.

@Joshua you can use set_inode_field with debugfs.  It's not straightforward or always possible, and requires root access but still exploitable.

Regarding changing ctime attribute, this answer sounds relevant here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17066309.

@Joshua You can also do it with the system time modification.  date -s "2023-01-01 12:00:00" && touch test will result in a ctime of jan 1 2023.

@Joshua you can also mv an existing, old file, and give it a new name. It keeps its original creation date (at least on my Arch, testing on an ext4 filesystem). Jesse_b, it might be worth pointing out that if the OP wants to use find, then find ... -exec my_virus_scanner {} + would be a better approach than saving into files and then reading from those files. Especially if they aren't using -print0 to create the files.

You effectively list debugfs with "If you write directly to the disk" and also "You can modify the system time" is well covered.

@Joshua cool so we are in agreement then?

I wouldn’t say “File modification times in linux are weird”, I would say “File modification times are weird” — in particular, the caveats around ctime/mtime are mostly (if not entirely) related to file systems that aren’t POSIX-compliant and aren’t Linux-specific.

@terdon ctime is not creation time, it's inode change time. Renaming a file should update ctime. Use ls -lc filename to see the ctime.

Argh, of course it isn't! Sorry, @Barmar, bit of a PEBKAC moment there. Thanks.

"You can modify the system time when modifying a file and then change it back to manipulate the file modify time" I think when an attacker can set your system time then the system isn't yours anymore, anyway. Also, it raises the question how it could come that far.

@rexkogitans The overwhelming majority of vulnerabilities require root access to exploit, that makes them significantly harder to exploit but doesn't mean you ignore them.  There are also a large group of exploits that allow an attacker to elevate privileges...

Doing file timestamp change verification by hand via find for the purpose of detecting malware is cumbersome. And it's likely that you might do it wrong (in your post, as said in a comment, you check only for files modified less than 1 day ago -- why?).
Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, it's better to use more complete and complex tools explicitly designed to check for file changes via checksum computation or other means, such as:

chkrootkit
rkhunter
aide

etc.

sorry that was a mistake - entering `-type f' twice.

Besides the more technical arguments in other answers: You aren’t avoiding a full-system scan — you’re just doing a cruder one than the program otherwise would. In your approach, find is scanning the whole system for recently touched files, before passing those to the antivirus program.  That’s exactly equivalent to an antivirus program full-scan where for each file the first thing it checks is the timestamp, and then it moves straight on if the file isn’t recently touched.  If this added speed without compromising security, don’t you think the programs would already do it?  The designers of any decent antivirus software are putting a fair bit of effort and expertise into scanning files as efficiently as possible — and they’ve decided that the obvious shortcut “start by filtering on timestamps” isn’t a good tradeoff.
